# Restkit doesn't load data on second request

Tags: ios, restkit

I'm developing an ios app using restkit and core data to query json from a server.

I noticed that the first time I open the app, restkit works properly, but the second time, it refuses to load any data.

When I enabled the restkit trace log, I saw that restkit printed lots of "skip mapping / no data change" message, and this takes a very long time.

What does that message mean? Why does it take so much time?

Comment: What do you mean under "it refuses to load any data"? It does not load from web or from DB, or something else?

Comment: It loads from the web, I could see if from the log. but it never triggers the callback function saying it's done, instead it looped somewhere inside restkit, printing the message "skip mapping"